# Why is Model.scoped generating invalid SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I run `Book.scoped({:conditions => ['books.index LIKE ?','%query%']})` I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "index": syntax error: SELECT * FROM "books" WHERE (books.index like '%query%')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: INDEX is a keyword in SQL.  In raw SQL you'd double-quote: "INDEX"; not sure how you'd fix in Rails aside from renaming the column.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit goes to [Adam Bernier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42346/adam-bernier) for pointing out that `index` is a SQL keyword (cf. comment on question). I am reposting the solution here so that this question gets marked as answered.

While

```
Book.scoped({:conditions => ['`index` LIKE ?','%query%']})
```

works, for peace of mind, I decided to rename the column.